# MYSQL trigger to create id

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to make a id from 2 fields

**producten_categorien** is filled with the follow data:

```
productcat_id    productcat_name    productcat_count     productcat_code
1                Sound              1                    SOU
2                Light              1                    LIG
3                Vision             1                    VIS
```

I want to make an id like `VIS0001 (productcat_code + productcat_count)`

I always get VIS000 back could you guys help me?

### Below you see my code:

```
USE `jarent`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `klanten_BINS`
BEFORE INSERT ON `producten`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE productcat VARCHAR(45);
  DECLARE productcatcount INT unsigned;

  SELECT productcat_code INTO productcat FROM producten_categorien WHERE productcat_id = NEW.product_catid;
  SELECT productcat_count INTO productcatcount FROM producten_categorien WHERE productcat_id = NEW.product_catid;

  SET productcatcount = productcatcount + 1;

  UPDATE producten_categorien SET productcat_count = productcatcount WHERE productcat_id = NEW.product_catid;

  SET NEW.product_id = CONCAT(productcat, LPAD(productcatcount, 4, '0'));
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all an attempt to maintain id sequences on your own will fail miserably under load. Two sessions trying to insert a new product can easily produce the same `product_id`.

At least make use of `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`. Better yet drop it altogether and just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for ids.

That being said here is an improved and working version of your trigger:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER klanten_BINS
BEFORE INSERT ON producten
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE productcat VARCHAR(45);

  UPDATE producten_categorien 
     SET productcat_count = LAST_INSERT_ID(productcat_count + 1)
  WHERE productcat_id = NEW.product_catid;

  SELECT productcat_code INTO productcat
    FROM producten_categorien 
   WHERE productcat_id = NEW.product_catid;

  SET NEW.product_id = CONCAT(productcat, LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deb8d2/1)** demo

Further reading:

- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)